# Django with react or node js with react have more openings in future

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

Which language should I concentrate , Django with React or Node with React ?
Which have more opportunities in future ?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam
https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would concentrate both and even more when I have time. It's because there're many tech jobs today require developers to know more than 2 back-end languages and a few front-end frameworks. If you know more, your chances to get a job is much quicker than whoever knows less than you.